# SharePoint documents library property

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, document-library, js

We have a. SharePoint library  where users uploads their documents.
Once a document is uploaded when somebody click on document it open the document itself
I would like to change it to view property of that particular documents like we have in SharePoint Lists.
I want that when a user click on the title it should open the property of that document not the document

Can you please suggest how we can achieve it using JS or any other source

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that changing the default SharePoint behaviour for document links is a good idea. Do you know that you can include the "Edit" icon in the document library view that does what you describe without using any code?

[image]

Click the Edit icon to edit the document properties, click the document name to open the document. SharePoint has been working like this since the beginning.

In SharePoint online there is a new experience where the document properties are showing in a side panel when the document is selected with a tick box.

[image]

Clicking the document name will open the document.

Please don't confuse your users by changing that default behaviour.